# Simplify code and avoid instanceOf and null check

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, null, option-type

I want to simplify the code (e.g. by using Optionals)

```
private String formatValue(Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (value instanceof Date) {
        return MyUtils.formatDate((Date)value, Constant.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS);
    }

    return value.toString();
}
```

value can be: `null`, `String`, `Date`

Comment: If this is indeed the logic of your code, then there is no safer way to do it.

Comment: Can you show us how this function is *used* in your code?

Comment: callers:writeLog(" " + formatValue(diff.getFieldName())); // returns String
          writeLog("  blah: " + formatValue(diff.getLeft())); // returns Date or null

Comment: @DerBenniAusA - To improve the question, use the "edit" link, rather than posting code in comments. *"returns Date or null"* Your code seems to be allowing for strings as well, which is why I asked the question. I'm curious about the declared type of the value you're passing in (for instance, the return type of `getLeft` in that example). Are you passing in things typed as `String` and `Date`? Or are you passing in things typed as `Object`?

Comment: .getLeft() etc. is from apache tuple pair

Comment: @DerBenniAusA - Let's assume not everyone knows the Apache tuple pair semantics off the top of their head and actually **just state the return type**, eh? And is it not parameterized? Help people who are clearly trying to help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:     /**
     * <p>Gets the left element from this pair.</p>
     *
     * <p>When treated as a key-value pair, this is the key.</p>
     *
     * return the left element, may be null
     */
    public abstract L getLeft();

Answer (score 6):

I'd handle it with overloading:

```
private String formatValue(String value) {
    return value;
}
private String formatValue(Date value) {
    return MyUtils.formatDate(value, Constant.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS);
}
```

...and fix any code passing it `null`.

If you *really* have to handle `null`, then:

```
private String formatValue(String value) {
    return value;
}
private String formatValue(Date value) {
    return value == null ? null : MyUtils.formatDate(value, Constant.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS);
}
```

---

The above works provided the type of what you're passing in is known at compile-time, which normally would be the case. But **if** you have to handle the possibility that the only type known at compile-time is `Object`, you can add an `Object` version as well:

```
private string formatValue(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof Date) {
        return this.formatValue((Date)value);
    }
    return value == null ? null : value.toString();
}
```

That starts feeling like more code, but it lets the normal path (where the type is known) go straight to the appropriate method, and you'd only supply this if you were dealing with something dynamic where you were stuck with `Object`.

Or you can *just* have the `Object` version. It doesn't have fewer checks, but it seems a bit simpler and clearer to me.

Comment: Overloading indeed seems the best way to go, but since the question asks to use optional, I would suggest to change the input to be `Optional<String>` and `Optional<Date>` and the `return !value.isPresent ? ...`

Comment: @Dimitris - Well, the Optional thing is just an "e.g.", not a requirement if I'm reading it right. I think Optional would just complicate, rather than simplify, in this specific case.

Comment: One details, if the variable used is an `Object`, since the original method allowed it, `Object o = new Date()` won't return the expected value (supposing you have a `formatValue(Object o)` define here of course.

Comment: @AxelH - Indeed, that's why [I asked the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574951/simplify-code-and-avoid-instanceof-and-null-check#comment97849000_55574951). But I should have edited the answer as well.

Comment: To be fair, I would simply use a `@deprecated private String formatValue(Object)` using `instanceof` redirecting to the new methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a functional version of your code, you can do this (using 2 Optionals):

```
private String formatValue(Object value) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(value)
            .map(v -> Optional.of(v)
                        .filter(d -> d instanceof Date)
                        .map(d -> MyUtils.formatDate((Date) d, 
                                      Constant.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS))
                        .orElseGet(() -> v.toString()))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

This is hard to read, though; so I'd personally keep your original version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Optional` from java 8:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(value).filter(v -> v instanceof Date || v instanceof String)
    .map(v -> v instanceof Date ? MyUtils.formatDate((Date)v, Constant.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS : v)
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: The `instanceof` part is missing here, so if `value` is not null but not a date in the intended format, an exception will be fired instead of falling back to `value.toString()`

Comment: You're both right. Also I assumed, that we know, that `Date` is the type. Corrected it

Comment: @Andronicus `.filter(v -> v instanceof Date)` will incorrectly eliminate non-null objects that aren't `Date`s

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wouldn't the return type be incorrect?

Comment: that contains even more instanceofs?

Answer (score 0):

For Date as one of Date or String, one cannot avoid instanceOf. As null is not a Date:

```
if (value instanceof Date) {
    value = MyUtils.formatDate((Date)value, Constant.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS);
}
return Optional.ofNullable(value).map(String.class::cast);
```

A `Object::toString` would be safer, but now a fail-fast cast exception would be thrown on erroneous values.